# How to mix an upper bound with null values in a generic Kotlin class

Tags: kotlin, generics, nullable

I tried to derive a delegate class from AbstractList with an upper bound Comparable and want to use lists as delegate which can contain null values.
Here's my implementation:

```
package org.baier.test


class MyList<out T: Comparable<@kotlin.UnsafeVariance T>>(private val delegate: List<T>) : AbstractList<T>() {
    override val size = delegate.size

    override fun get(index: Int): T {
        return delegate[index]
    }
}

fun main() {
    val delegate1: List<Int> = listOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
    val list1 = MyList(delegate1)
    val delegate2: List<Int?> = listOf(1, 2, 3, null, 4, 5)
    val list2 = MyList(delegate2)
}
```

In the main method I tried to instantiate the class Mylist with both a List and a List<Int?>.
Why do I get a compiler error for the latter one saing

> "Type mismatch. Required:Comparable<Int?> Found: Int?"

Why is Int? not of type Comparable<Int?>?

Answer (score 1):

`Int` is defined as a `Comparable<Int>`. An `Int?` is  `Comparable<Int>?` but not a `Comparable<Int?>?` because `Int` does not specifically implement `Comparable<Int?>`.

There are at least a couple of reasons for this:

1. It's ambiguous whether null should be considered greater or less than any specific integer value.
2. You can't actually uses a nullable variable as a Comparable to sort something because you can't call `compareTo()` on `null`. For example `(null as Int?)?.compareTo(1)` would return `null` rather than -1 / 0 / 1 so you couldn't actually use it to sort something. `Comparable.compareTo()`'s contract is that it works the same in both directions, so this is impossible with a null value. You can define your own Comparable that works with a nullable value, which might have some uses, but not for sorting a list using the standard library sort functions.

If you're not using this class for sorting, you may want to define some other upper bound.

Answer (score 0):

The reasons why it is not working are those already proposed by Tenfour04.

Anyway if you want to make it work also with nulls, you could try to say that your List is of type `List<T?>` and then define some kind of default for the `get` overriding when it happens to be null. Like the following:

```
class MyList<out T: Comparable<@kotlin.UnsafeVariance T>(private val delegate: List<T?>, private val nullValuesProvider: (Int) -> T) : AbstractList<T>() {
    override val size = delegate.size

    override fun get(index: Int): T {
        return delegate[index] ?: nullValuesProvide(index)
    }
}
```

or in alternative, a default value for nulls:

```
class MyList<out T: Comparable<@kotlin.UnsafeVariance T>(private val delegate: List<T?>, private val defaultIfNull: T) : AbstractList<T>() {
    override val size = delegate.size

    override fun get(index: Int): T {
        return delegate[index] ?: defaultIfNull
    }
}
```